# Continuity of a function over a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

The definition I have of continuity of a function $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at a point $c\in D$ is that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if for all sequeunces $(x_n)$ in $D$ s.t. $x_n \rightarrow c$, we have $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(c)$.

So my question is, if we say $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on an interval $[a,b]$, are we saying that:

for any $c \in [a,b]$, we have that for all sequeunces $(x_n)$ in $D$ s.t. $x_n \rightarrow c$, we have $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(c)$

or are we saying that:

for any $c \in [a,b]$, we have that for all sequeunces $(x_n)$ in $[a,b]$ s.t. $x_n \rightarrow c$, we have $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(c)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the former. To say a function is continuous on a subset $C$ of domain $D$, it means to be continuous at every point $c \in C$. To be (sequentially) continuous at a point $c \in C$ means that, for all sequences $(x_n)$ in $D$ such that $x_n \to c$, we have $f(x_n) \to f(c)$.